# How to append the lines using SED or AWK until a particular pattern does not matches?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to append the line which does not start with a `given pattern`. But i am unable to do that using `sed`. Plz help me to solve the problem using either `sed` or `awk`. For an Example:

**INPUT:**

```
18:55:42[pool-1-thread-2] INFO jfileupload.download.http.a - Download completed
18:55:42[HTTPDOWNLOAD] ERROR jfileupload.download.ui.DownloadTransferUI - 
java.io.IOException: Failed to show URI:file:/home/rahul/Desktop/
    at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.launch(XDesktopPeer.java:114)
    at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.open(XDesktopPeer.java:77)
    at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:272)
    at jfileupload.download.ui.DownloadTransferUI.a(Unknown Source)
    at jfileupload.download.http.HTTPDownloadTransfer.a(Unknown Source)
    at jfileupload.download.a.a.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:55:43[MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - ReferenceQueueThread interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ReferenceQueueThread.run(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1122)
```

**Required Output:**

```
18:55:42[pool-1-thread-2] INFO jfileupload.download.http.a - Download completed
18:55:42[HTTPDOWNLOAD] ERROR jfileupload.download.ui.DownloadTransferUI -java.io.IOException: Failed to show URI:file:/home/rahul/Desktop/, at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.launch(XDesktopPeer.java:114),  at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.open(XDesktopPeer.java:77), at java.awt.Desktop.open,(Desktop.java:272),    at jfileupload.download.ui.DownloadTransferUI.a(Unknown Source),    at jfileupload.download.http.HTTPDownloadTransfer.a(Unknown Source),    at jfileupload.download.a.a.run(Unknown Source),    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:55:43[MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - ReferenceQueueThread interrupted,java.lang.InterruptedException,  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method),    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove,(ReferenceQueue.java:135),   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151),    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ReferenceQueueThread.run(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1122)
```

In the above input i want to append the next line into current line with `,` until the new line start with such pattern `18:55:42`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not tried it but this should work

```
awk '/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/{x=$0}{a[x]=a[x]?a[x]", "$0:$0}END{for (i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

.

```
/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/         If this pattern is matched

{x=$0}                         Set x to the value of the line

{a[x]=a[x]?a[x]", "$0:$0}      Create associative array with x($0) using ternary
                               operator to check there is a value in a[x] to
                               begin with. Adds the current lines value to the 
                               a[x]

END{for (i in a)print a[i]}   When all records are processed loop through array 
                              and output values
```

Comment: can you explain the working of above. It would be very usefull for all of us. Thanks, its working.